Pyspark merge or flatten two rows columns into single row based on a condition
I have a data set like this:
Id,col_a,col_b,account_type
James Butt,a1_col_a_data_1,a1_col_b_data_1,1
James Butt,a1_col_a_data_2,a1_col_b_data_2,2
Art Venere,a1_col_a_data_3,a1_col_b_data_3,1
Lenna Paprocki,a1_col_a_data_4,a1_col_b_data_4,1
Lenna Paprocki,a1_col_a_data_5,a1_col_b_data_5,2
John Doe,a1_col_a_data_6,a1_col_b_data_6,1
Mitsue Tollner,a1_col_a_data_7,a1_col_b_data_7,1
Leota Dilliard,a1_col_a_data_8,a1_col_b_data_8,1
Sage Wieser,a1_col_a_data_9,a1_col_b_data_9,1
Sage Wieser,a1_col_a_data_10,a1_col_b_data_10,2

Visually:

Using pyspark I want to merge columns based on the column "account_type.", Note that the account types will be limited (max 10). Expecting the output as:
Id,col_a,col_b,col_a_account_type_2,col_b_account_type_2
James Butt,a1_col_a_data_1,a1_col_b_data_1,a1_col_a_data_2,a1_col_b_data_2
Art Venere,a1_col_a_data_3,a1_col_b_data_3,,
Lenna Paprocki,a1_col_a_data_4,a1_col_b_data_4,a1_col_a_data_5,a1_col_b_data_5
John Doe,a1_col_a_data_6,a1_col_b_data_6,,
Mitsue Tollner,a1_col_a_data_7,a1_col_b_data_7,,
Leota Dilliard,a1_col_a_data_8,a1_col_b_data_8,,
Sage Wieser,a1_col_a_data_9,a1_col_b_data_9,a1_col_a_data_10,a1_col_b_data_10

Or visually like this:

Any help is really appreciated! Thank you!

Did my answer help to solve this problem? If so, please accept the answer.
If not, please let me know any additional information so I can help to solve the issue.

PySparks Pivot should suit your use case
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot.html
Here's an example of how to use it for your scenario,
Set-up
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

Create a new column that is the string format that you want to use when referencing account_type in the pivoted columns
df = df.withColumn("account_type_str",
                         F.concat(F.lit("account_type_"), F.col("account_type").cast(T.StringType())))

Pivot the data on Id, use first to get the first value
More info about Pyspark First: link
pivot_df = df.groupBy("Id")\
             .pivot("account_type_str")\
             .agg(F.first("col_a").alias("col_a"), F.first("col_b").alias("col_b"))

Sample output
pivot_df.show(2)




id
account_type_1_col_a
account_type_1_col_b
account_type_2_col_a
account_type_2_col_b




Art Venere
a1_col_a_data_3
a1_col_b_data_3
NULL
NULL


James Butt
a1_col_a_data_1
a1_col_b_data_1
a1_col_a_data_2
a1_col_b_data_2




Thank you for responding.
I end up splitting the data frame into two data frames, one for account type 1 and the other for account type 2. I perform various logic and then join both together at the end.
Experts - Feel free to challenge me.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
